# Need only 1 Result from Many to Many Relation Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-one

I have 3 tables with Many to Many relation.

**Table1**: shops -> name, location_id

**Table2**: items

**Pivot table**: item_shop -> item_id, shop_id

A Shop can have multiple items on its store and a item can be in multiple shops.

What I want is to get items result with only 1 shop info located in an area.

My current query:

```
$query = Item::whereIn('items.id', $itemids);

$query->whereHas('shops', function($q) use($city_id){
       $q->where('shops.city_id', $city_id);
     });

            //======= SLOW query
$query->with(['shops' => function($q) use ($city_id){
         $q->where('shops.city_id', $city_id);
});
$items = $query->get();
```

This query works but its slow on with(), probably because it retrieves all shops within the area .(`$city_id`) so then I need to use `$item->shops->first()->name` to get 1 shop. What I need only 1 shop result.
I cant seem to find something like one to one relation with pivot.
tables are already indexed.
I am using Laravel 5.3
Any suggestion how to achive it?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the way you write your query.

Assuming your many-to-many relationship is called `items` in your `Shop` model:

```php
$shop = Shop::with('items')->where('city_id', $city_id)->first();

// do something with $shop which now contains items collection
```

Comment: What I need is items result which exists in certain city with 1 shop information.

Comment: @TomKur that is what my answer gives you.